# Any python library to access quickbooks?

Tags: python, api, quickbooks

I want to integrate my mobile POS system with quickbooks. I need customers, sellers, inventory & post orders & invoices.

I have not not been able to find a python library for this. Is there one available?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be useful to someone

First, you have to automize a POS

[Orthosie Point of sale system written in Python](https://github.com/maxolasersquad/orthosie)

[Wxpos Python cross platform point of sale software](https://code.google.com/p/wxpos/) (Unfortunately, it is now closed, but there has read only access, good for research purposes also)

Second, you have to integrate POS collected data with the quickbooks

[A Python library for accessing the Quickbooks API](https://github.com/sidecars/python-quickbooks)

> A Python library for accessing the Quickbooks API. Complete rework of quickbooks-python.